# Clojure - refer to a defrecord function

Tags: error-handling, clojure, architecture

How do I refer a function of a record ?

For the context, I am using Stuart Sierra's component. So I have a record like this :

```
(defrecord MyComponent []
  component/Lifecycle
  (start [component]
    ...)

  (stop [component]
    ...)
```

However in the README, it is stated :

> ...you could wrap the body of stop in a try/catch that ignores all
>   exceptions. That way, errors stopping one component will not prevent
>   other components from shutting down cleanly.

I would like, however, to use [Dire](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire) for that. Now how do I reference that `stop` function to use with Dire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two natural options:

1. You could use Dire to handle errors for `component/stop` (and possibly `start`):

   ```
   (dire.core/with-handler! #'com.stuartsierra.component/stop
     …)
   ```

   This way you'd be committing to handling errors for all components you might use in your system and any calls to `component/stop` made anywhere in your application.
2. You could introduce a top-level function to handle your component's `stop` logic, register it with Dire and have your `component/stop` implementation merely delegate to it, and perhaps handle `start` similarly:

   ```
   (defn start-my-component [component]
     …)

   (defn stop-my-component [component]
     …)

   (dire.core/with-handler! #'start-my-component
     …)

   (dire.core/with-handler! #'stop-my-component
     …)

   (defrecord MyComponent […]
     component/Lifecycle
     (start [component]
       (start-my-component component))

     (stop [component]
       (stop-my-component component)))
   ```

Comment: Those options sound good, however does that mean that there is no way to reference all `stop` methods from a particular record without wrapping a separate method, correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't wrap `stop`, you wrap the body of stop - that is, everything but the argument declaration gets wrapped in your `dire/with-handler!` block, or whatever other method of error catching you prefer.

```
(defstruct MyComponent []
   component/Lifecycle
   (start [component]
      (try (/ 1 0)
        (catch Exception e)
        (finally component))))
```

Note that however you handle errors, you will break the system if you do not return the component from your `start` method.